# running an application inside ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I've written an application in C# that I would now like to host within an ASP.NET website (MVC 2).

The application can become quite resource intensive so I would like to set up the system in such a way that each user downloads the application and runs it locally, but still within the web page that I provide.

My first idea to solve this problem was to host the program within a silverlight application. However, the app I want to host was not compiled for Silverlight, and I would like to use MySQL in it, which also appears to not be possible directly (ie without a web service in between).

The bottom line is that don't have experience with these things directly yet, and I need to research the way to make any solution possible. So I would really appreciate some input to put me in the right direction, and not have to implement 3 wrong options before finding the right one. I would also really like to avoid JavaScript if at all possible.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I probably should have specified to begin with what the application is exactly.
The application as I want to host it on the website is a simple chat program. It needs an input box and text output. The old windows forms application won't have to run in ASP, but I want to use the class library behind it, which is a chatbot engine. That engine is the part that can be rather resource intensive.

Comment: Next time, describe your requirements before you start developing your application.

Comment: I didn't develop the application for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

So you wrote a "rich client" application and you want to serve it as a web/silverlight application. This is not possible without changing the architecture of your app, as you probably guess, expecially because you have to interface a database. If rewriting the application to support such architecture is not an option, the best in order to me is to use [Remote Desktop](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Connect-to-another-computer-using-Remote-Desktop-Connection), but you have to pay for licenses in order to support many connections.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is not a web application then it will not run on the server. The only thing your server does is to provide a download location. For that, you wouldn't need a MVC site - static pages could fit. The programming model between normal applications running on the client and server applications running on IIS is completely different. So in short: you won't be able to host your client application in ASP.NET MVC. If this is a requirement you will end up rewriting the application.

If your application is ASP.NET WebForms and it becomes too resource hungry, then you probably won't solve it by just switching to MVC. You have different options then: more resources on the server side, analyzing what could be done to lower the resources required or moving away from a server based application. This is not a black/white decision, maybe a combination might fit.